# Watin script for handling Ajax popup

Tags: c#, .net, watin

I'm using WatiN testing tool and i'm writing c#.net scripts. I've a scenario where i need to change the theme of my web page, so to do this i need to click on a image button which opens a ajax popup with the image and "Apply Theme" button which is below the image now i need to click on the button so how to do this please suggest some solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So first click your button that throws up the popup, and .WaitUntilExists() for the button inside the popup.

```
IE.Button("ShowPopup").click()
IE.Button("PopupButtonID").WaitUntilExists()
IE.Button("PopupButtonID").click()
```

This may not work in the case the button on the popup exists but is hidden from view.  In that case you could try the .WaitUntil() and specify an attribute to look for.

```
IE.Button("ButtonID").WaitUntil("display","")
```

Comment: Thanks for replying but the method is not working. wn i click on the image to aplly theme the popup appears has a new window (not as windows internet explorer) it contains image in the top and a button ("Apply Theme") below it.In the title panel there is maximize, minimize and close button. I need to click on the button ("Apply Theme") to make the theme apply to the main window.

Comment: I'm not too sure what your asking here.  You basically need the ID or some other way to 'get' the 'Apply Theme' button with WatiN.  Once you have that, you simply need to .WaitUntilExists(), and then .Click() that button.

Answer (score 1):

The Ajax pop-up itself shouldn't pose a problem if you handle the timing of the control loading asynchronously. If you are using the ajax control toolkit, you can solve it like this

```
int timeout = 20;
for (i=0; i < timeout; i++)
{
    bool blocked = Convert.ToBoolean(ie.Eval("Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().get_isInAsyncPostBack();"));
    if (blocked)
    {
       System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200);
    }
    else
    {
        break;
    }
 }
```

With the control visible you then should be able to access it normally.

Watin 1.1.4 added support for WaitUntil on controls as well, but I haven't used it personally.

```
// Wait until some textfield is enabled
textfield.WaitUntil("disable", false.ToSting, 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not using any ajax control toolkit and in the popup there is no text field as i've mentioned there is only a image and a button below it, which i need to click in order to apply that image as theme.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a post about how I do ajax synchronization, since I was having problems with WaitUntilExists:  http://lebobitz.wordpress.com/2011/03/06/synchronizing-watin-and-ajax-with-jquery/